# C++ passing temporary stack object as reference to function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

```
template<class D>
class Animal{
public:
    D a;
    Animal(){
        a=0;
    }
};
template<class D>
Animal<D>& addAnimal(Animal<D>& ans, const Animal<D>& a, const Animal<D>& b){
    ans.a = a.a + b.a;
    return ans;
}

//an overloaded simpler method for the one above
template<class D>
Animal<D> addAnimal(const Animal<D>& a, const Animal<D>& b){
    return addAnimal( Animal<D>(),a,b);
}
int main() {    
    Animal<int> a;
    Animal<int> b;
    Animal<int> c = addAnimal(a,b);
}
```

The following doesn't compile. Why not? I know I can fix this by making the `ans` parameter pass by value OR changing the call to that method by doing:

```
template<class D>
Animal<D> addAnimal(const Animal<D>& a, const Animal<D>& b){
    Animal<D> ans;
    return addAnimal(ans,a,b);
}
```

I want a better understanding of pass by reference and how to call the default constructor of a stack object.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
return addAnimal( Animal<D>(),a,b);
```

does not work because `Animal<D>()` is a temporary object, which cannot be used in a function call that expects a non-`const` lvalue reference.

More importantly, it is not clear to me why you need the overload

```
template<class D>
Animal<D>& addAnimal(Animal<D>& ans, const Animal<D>& a, const Animal<D>& b) { ... }
```

You can implement the simpler, two argument, function as:

```
template<class D>
Animal<D> addAnimal(const Animal<D>& a, const Animal<D>& b){
   Animal<D> ans;
   ans.a = a.a + b.b;
   return ans;
}
```

and get rid of the other one altogether.

Comment: I want to avoid having a copy happen after I return from the last function you described. I read a lot about return value optimization, but I still wanted to guarantee it does not copy memory wherever possible. Is this unnecessary on my part?

Comment: @akarshkumar0101, I woundn't worry about that until it's a proven performance bottleneck.